# can't access sqlite database of Android in Genymotion

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

im trying place my prepoppulated-database to Android emulator(Genymotion) 
i do from this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lrMoccPBZ14&t=241s

in his case ,he saw the database see pic below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPi03.png)

but in my computer it have only "con" file ,see pic beow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUIR4.png)

so if anyone face the same problem and can solve it please tell me how to fix plz, tx in advance.

Comment: have you tried to expand a litle bit the column with the name? im pretty sure that 
'con' its from com.example.bla.bla

Comment: lol, shame me,thx a lot u save my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That con is actually com. You need to expand the width of the name column.

e.g. Instead of :-

[image]

Expand the column :-

[image]

and then find the folder that equates to your package name e.g :-

[image]

As you can see there are a number of packages i.e. those in the highlighted area. You very likely won't have as many.